# Android - Dynamically changing ImageView s from an array

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an array of Images, and I am trying to change image views to match these drawables.  For some reason, they are simply not being drawn at all.

Here is my code so far:

```
TypedArray answerResources = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.answers);
int resId = answerResources.getResourceId(randomQuestion, -1);
answerResources.recycle();

int [] questionAnswers = res.getIntArray(resId);

firstAnswerImg .setImageResource(questionAnswers[0]);
secondAnswerImg.setImageResource(questionAnswers[1]);
thirdAnswerImg .setImageResource(questionAnswers[2]);
fourthAnswerImg.setImageResource(questionAnswers[3]);
```

Here is the xml:

```
<array name = "answers">
    <item>@array/questionOneAnswers</item>
    <item>@array/questionTwoAnswers</item>
    <item>@array/questionThreeAnswers</item>
...
</array>

    <integer-array name = "questionOneAnswers">
        <item>@drawable/da</item>
        <item>@drawable/sk</item>
        <item>@drawable/cq</item>
        <item>@drawable/ht</item>
    </integer-array>
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: My bad, I see the nesting now. I think you need to use typed arrays (just like you did for the outer ones), like so:

```
<array name="answers">
  <item>@array/questionOneAnswers</item>
  <item>@array/questionTwoAnswers</item>
  <item>@array/questionThreeAnswers</item>
</array>
...
<array name="questionOneAnswers">
  <item>@drawable/da</item>
  <item>@drawable/sk</item>
  <item>@drawable/cq</item>
  <item>@drawable/ht</item>
</array>
```

Then, pull from the array like so:

```
TypedArray answers = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.answers);
int questionOneAnswersId = answerResources.getResourceId(0, 0));
TypedArray questionOneAnswers = res.obtainTypedArray(questionOneAnswersId);
firstAnswerImg.setImageDrawable(questionOneAnswers.getDrawable(0);
....
```

Comment: this works, but not what I'm looking for.  I want to access it through nested arrays.  See my original xml

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. Edited my answer, check it out now.